# How to stop $interval on leaving ui-state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, intervals

Angular, UI-router. Using $interval in a controller of a state like so:

```
$scope.Timer = null;

$scope.startTimer = function () { 
    $scope.Timer = $interval($scope.Foo, 30000);
};

$scope.stopTimer = function () {
    if (angular.isDefined($scope.Timer)) {
        $interval.cancel($scope.Timer);
    }
};
```

The problem? The timer persists upon leaving the state. My understanding was that the $scope and the controller are essentially "destroyed" when a state is left. So, based on that, the timer should stop (Within the controller, I am cancelling the timer when moving around, that works - but it persists if I navigate to a diff state). What am I misunderstanding here?

I guess since interval and timeout are [services](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/timeout-interval.html) in angular, they are available everywhere, but I still don't understand how they see functions in the not-initialized controller, unless it's copied. Is my solution to just use regular good-old js interval?

Comment: A vanilla timer would also persist, unless you clear it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

clear interval on [**`$destroy`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Like this

```
$scope.$on("$destroy",function(){
    if (angular.isDefined($scope.Timer)) {
        $interval.cancel($scope.Timer);
    }
});
```

Comment: Edit: Problem solved, thank you very much! Please fix spelling on "destroy" above - I cannot change it due to 6-character min-edit length.

Comment: Why do you have to check `if (angular.isDefined($scope.Timer))`?

Comment: If `$scope.Timer` is defined then `$interval.cancel($scope.Timer);` may throw an exception @BornToCode

Comment: Yes I understood that, but in what scenario will `$scope.Timer` won't be defined?

Comment: @BornToCode you didn't trigger `$scope.startTimer` and went to another controller